How should I get clients for volunteer graphic design work?
I am new here, but figured trying this was worth a shot. I am a recent high school graduate, looking to do some volunteer graphic design work to build a portfolio for applying to colleges and future jobs/internships.
For some context, despite my age, I am a very experienced designer. I have been working in the Adobe Creative Cloud (Illustrator, Photoshop, Indesign, Acrobat) for going on 4 years now, and have a very good practical understanding of the programs and their uses. I also worked as a graphic designer at a print shop for about 8 months and worked personally with many clients there. I am quite experienced in graphic design, especially for my age, and since I have experience working on design work for clients, I feel that I would be qualified to do some design work for some organizations.
That being said, I am struggling to figure out ways to connect with organizations that could use these services, and am not sure how I would reach out to any of them. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find clients to donate volunteer work to, or just how to find graphic design volunteer work?
Thanks in advance to anyone who's willing to help out!

If you are an experienced designer you would not be working for free. That is something experience teaches you.

Welcome to GD.SE and the graphic design world! See this post for why not to work for free. See this post for ways you can design for free. For how to find more clients, see this post

Savvy clients are often aware that "one gets what one pays for". Your best bet is to seek organizations looking for volunteers.. not clients wanting free work. Working for free for random clients typically offers zero benefit to the designer. Clients looking for free work aren't "real world" clients.

...so what I'm reading is that you're not a very experienced designer but a designer with 8 months of experience. Unless you did some professional work in those 4 years prior. Is that correct?

For some more context, I was hired at the print shop February, 2023 and have been working in concurrent enrollment college programs since I stopped working there. Before I began working as a graphic designer there, I worked with numerous clients through my school's graphic design program. This all puts me at a lot more experience than 8 months total, since I have also worked with other clients. I'm not claiming that I am some incredible, professionally involved designer, but I think I do have enough experience to qualify me for doing some volunteer work for people that may need it :)

Just because somebody's willing to work for free, doesn't mean clients will be rushing in to get the free work.
You need to be aware there are many other people using the same apps, and having the same experience and struggles.
Also, finding your own clients can be a challenge, there's an extra level of skills involved for independent employment, otherwise the most predictable path to income is looking for a full time job, not doing random work for free.
